# Web APIs FileReader() hide download option

Tags: vue.js, pdf, filereader, webapi

I've successfully integrated the [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader) that renders a file from a BLOB so the user can view and interact with it, however the revised criteria states that the user shouldn't be allowed to download the document now.

The requirement is that the download icon is removed from the FileReader() but I can't seem to find a way of doing this, as it's baked into the actual Web API.

I started to write my own PDF viewer using a basic Vue to PDF package and adding custom controls but this is a bit of a monster and I'd like to avoid a complete re-write to remove one action.

Is there any way of removing the download CTA before it renders the PDF?

---

More context..

The PDF is rendered in the DOM from a BLOB that's passed via an end point I hook into with Axios. I then readAsDataURL(blob) and finally create the FileReader() result as a URL.createObjectURL(blob) to give me the data that I render as the canvas src to enable the PDF viewer. Unfortunately this can't be a PNG as it needs multi pages. Thee issue is that it's sensitive docs that can only be viewed on the portal, so it's to prevent users from easily downloading (aware they could just print screen).

Comment: The PDF is rendered in the DOM from a BLOB that's passed via an end point I hook into with Axios.
I then readAsDataURL(blob) and finally create the FileReader() result as a URL.createObjectURL(blob) to give me the data that I render as the canvas src to enable the PDF viewer.
Unfortunately this can't be a PNG as it needs multi pages.
Thee issue is that it's sensitive docs that can only be viewed on the portal, so it's to prevent users from easily downloading (aware they could just print screen).

Comment: Thanks @KJ, however I think you may have mis understood my problem or I wasn't clear.  My issue isn't rendering the PDF - that works absolutely fine.
The issue is that the Web API FileReader() library that renders the PDF viewer has a download icon built in which needs removing, as the documents shouldn't be able to be downloaded from the UI.
So my query is, when using the FileReader() (link in original post), is there a way to remove the download call to action?

Comment: When you readAsDataURL(blob) ... where do you think the data is? Do you think it exists somewhere in the ether of space? Or is it already downloaded?

Comment: Or better stated ... when you think you have come up with a solution then send me a link. I will send back a PDF. If you are looking at it in your browser, it can be saved exactly as is.

Comment: Thanks @KevinBrown, the issue isn't rendering the PDF - it's purely if the download option can be removed from the FileReader() Web API

Comment: Thanks @KJ, hm that's what I'd feared. Looks like the re-write is going to be my Friday :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.